# TF700 boot loop after update to CM10.1.2

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, boot-loop

The Transformer Pad TF700T worked almost fine with the previous Cyanogenmod10. Today I updated the pad with the CM-Update Manager. It downloaded the cm10.1.2 update package and then booted recovery. After the installation was completed I found the pad stuck at boot loop.

The Cyanogenmod circle circuits but then stucks, waits for a few seconds and then the pad reboots and the same happens again.

I Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance,
mrstrauss

EDIT:
I did a format of the cache partition as well as the dalvik cache. The result is still the same. It boots until the circle stops to circle and then it reboots.

Comment: Does it boot into safe mode successfully? Also, you might try to re-flash CM. Though not that often, but I've heard of cases where that helped. Wipe again, optionally factory-reset even, flash, do another wipe. If that doesn't help either, I'm out of ideas (except for going back to the last version you had working on the device).

Comment: I did not find any hint on entering safe mode on the transformer pad. 
Reflashing the update did not solve the problem. I flashed the previous - working - version of CM and it seems to boot normally into android.

Comment: So it's most likely a bug the specific CM version has with your device. You might wish to post that solution as answer, and accept it lateron to show a possible way to solve that issue.

Comment: Bug still exists in the new 10.1.3 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the previous, working version solved the problem. After that an installation of the gapps zip-package may be required.